# spacy3 - what is en_use_lg?

Tags: spacy-3

There is a usage of a pretrained pipeline model `en_use_lg` which is not in [Trained Models & Pipelines](https://spacy.io/models).

[spaCy - Universal Sentence Encoder](https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-universal-sentence-encoder)

```
nlp = spacy_universal_sentence_encoder.load_model('en_use_lg')
```

Is this similar to the Huggingface Hub where users can share their pretrained pipelines besides the ones officially provided by SpaCy and is `en_use_lg` one of them?